# How to truncate the extension for special case in Perl?

Tags: perl

I'm working on a script to truncate all the extensions for a file using the regex as below but it seem doesn't works well as this command does remove some data that I want as it will basically removing everything whenever it see a dot.

The regex I use currently:-

```
/\..*?$/
```

It would remove some files like

```
b10_120.00c.current.all   --> b10_120  
abc_10.77.log.bac.temp.ls --> abc_10
```

but I'm looking for an output in `b10_120.00c` and `abc_10.77`

Aside from that, is there a way to printout the output such as it keep certain extension only?  Such as for the above 2 examples, it will displays `b10_120.00c.current` and `abc_10.77.log`.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

The following will strip file name extensions off:

```
s/\.[^.]+$//;
```

#### Explanation

`\.` matches a literal `.`
`[^.]+` matches every character that is not a `.`
`$` till end of string

### Update

```
my ($new_file_name) = ( $file_name =~ m/^( [^.]+ \. [^.]+ )/x );
```

#### Explanation

`^` anchor at the start of the string
`[^.]+` matches every character that is not a `.`
`\.` matches a literal `.`
`[^.]+` matches every character that is not a `.`

#### Test

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More 'tests' => 2;

my %file_name_map = (
    'b10_120.00c.current.all'   => 'b10_120.00c',
    'abc_10.77.log.bac.temp.ls' => 'abc_10.77',
);

sub new_file_name {
    my $file_name = shift;
    my ($new_file_name) = ( $file_name =~ m/^( [^.]+ \. [^.]+ )/x );
    return $new_file_name;
}

for my $file_name ( keys %file_name_map ) {
    is $file_name_map{$file_name}, new_file_name($file_name),
      "Got $file_name_map{$file_name}";
}
```

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks for the answer.  I tried the expression you mentioned b4 such as $string =~ s/\.[^.]+$//g, and this expression only truncate the final extention for me.  SO in other words, if I'm using this expression it will give me this result -------------   b10_120.00c.current and abc_10.77.log.bac.temp

Comment: *[Grace](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1029082/grace)*: You are welcome. Sorry, I misunderstood. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks foe the anwer but it still didn't get what I want as your code will give (abc_10.77.log.bac.temp.ls
and b10_120.00c.current.all) as results but what I want is briefly b10_120.00c and abc_10.77.  Basically my current command of $string =~ s/\..*?$/ will help me to truncate all the extentions but it did trim down the necessary data when there is a floating number in the file.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: *[Grace](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1029082/grace)*: No problem. Search and replace does not happen in my updated answer. Therefore you have to use `$new_file_name` for the stripped version of the file name.

Comment: Hi Alan, I meant your my ($new_file_name) = ( $file_name =~ m/^( [^.]+ \. [^.]+ )/x ); gives me this result ((abc_10.77.log.bac.temp.ls and b10_120.00c.current.all).  May I know do you hav eany idea so that I can get a brief outsut such as only b10_120.00c and abc_10.77 which do not trim down the floating point?

Comment: *[Grace](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1029082/grace)*: Please run the test script that I added to my answer and see if the tests pass.

Comment: Hi Alan and all, I finally got this expression to match exactly what I want.  Posted here ($strings =~ s/\.[^\d]*?$//g ; ) for sharing with the rest in case anyone having same issue.  Thanks all for the helping hand, esp you Alan!

Answer (score 2):

```
$file =~ s/(\.[^.]+).*/$1/; # SO requires 30 chars in answer, that is stupid
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `\.` for the dot in the regular expression.

Also please explain in more details how you want to process file name.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of a regex, I would suggest using this package: 
http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Basename.html

Comment: how does this materially help the OP?  To strip suffices, @Grace would need to either explicitly list them verbatim or compose a regex (`qr//`)...

Comment: How does it materially hurt the OP? It's an option for investigation that might allow the OP to write clearer code to strip suffixes. As it is, the OP already needs to know what suffixes she wants to remove. It's not a misdirection, and it's not patently idiotic or unrelated to the topic.

Comment: For all we know the OP is *already using* `File::Basename::basename` with a botched regex passed in as a `@suffixlist` argument.  OP needs help specifying those suffices to remove, not with the mechanics of removal.  (I didn't downvote you, by the way.)